# Problems activating PWM output on PIC18F67K40 (MicroE clicker2 development board)

Tags: c, pic, pwm

First time asking a question on here so please forgive any mistakes. If any other information is needed I'll happily provide

I've been developing a project which requires using a PWM module, but I'm having no luck whatsoever getting an output from it. I've used CCP and PWM modules on different PIC models before with no problem, but now suddenly I've hit a brick wall with the 67K40.

I've cut down my code to the bare necessities, as even if I load this into the PIC separate from the rest of my program I don't see any output

```
void main(void)
{
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0;   //Set TRIS of C5 to output
    LATCbits.LATC5 = 0;     //Set output value of C5 to 0
    RC5PPS = 0x6;           //Connect C5 to CCP2  output 
    CCP2CON = 0x1C;         //Set CCP4 to PWM mode, left aligned
    CCPR2L = 0xC0;          //Set CCP2 low duty cycle register to 100%
    CCPR2H = 0xFF;          //Set CCP2 high duty cycle register to 100%  
    CCPTMRS0bits.C2TSEL = 0x0;  //set CCP2 timer source to timer 2
    PIE7bits.CCP2IE = 0;    //Turn off CCP2 interrupt
    T2RST = 0x00;
    T2PR = 0xFF;            //Set timer 2 PR register to FF
    T2TMR = 0x00;           //Set timer 2 count register to 0
    PIE5bits.TMR2IE = 0;    //Set timer 2 overflow interrupt off
    T2HLT = 0x00;             
    T2CLKCON = 0x01;        //Set timer 2 clock source to Fosc/4
    T2CON = 0xD0;           //Set timer 2 on, 1:32 prescaler
    CCP2CONbits.EN = 1;     //Turn on CCP2

    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you so, so much for any assistance or pointing in the right direction

Comment: Are you sure the PIC is 'running'?

Comment: I've run it with other instructions like simple I/O blinks with an LED and so on to make sure the whole system was still responsive. As far as I can tell everything seems to be running okay, though there's always room for me to make a mistake

Comment: Just gave it another shot with an incrementing variable inside the while loop, just to make sure there wasn't some odd background sleeping behaviour going on, but no luck, still no PWM output.

I'm really puzzled